# Link symbol from loaded swf to custom class dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, external, symbols

I have a project where I load an external file with asset symbols (assets.swf) into the main swf and then add the symbols to the display when needed. I want the classes associated with each symbol to be linked to a custom class at runtime in the document class. I'd really like to avoid defining the custom classes in the assets fla through the symbol properties.

In AS2, this was possible with Object.registerClass as below:

```
Object.registerClass("assetID",AssetClass);
this.attachMovie("assetID", "asset_mc", 0);
```

So the symbol was independent of the class it is linked to at runtime.

In AS3, I'm seeing references to registerClassAlias but there is very little reliable documentation of it available online.

Does anyone know of a way of doing what I'd like to do with registerClassAlias or any other way?

thanks!!!
matt

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to load your asset symbol and keep a reference to the loader.

```
assetsLoader.load(new URLRequest("assets.swf"));
```

When the loading is done you can retrieve your assets within the loaded SWF `ApplicationDomain`.

```
var assetClass:Class = assetsLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("MyAssetClass") as Class;
var asset:* = new assetClass();
```

**Note:** `MyAssetClass` should be defined inside `assets.swf`!

If you want further informations, [you can read this article](http://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/as3-load-assets-dynamically-for-better-performance-2/).

Comment: The reason I'm reluctant to define the classes in the asset swf is because I want them to be reusable with multiple projects with custom classes that extend the original asset classes. I was hoping to be able to define the classes through the main document class. And that way, when I'm developing, I don't have to keep going back to compile the asset swf every time I make a change to the code, and then compile the main swf to test.